# How to move camera eye position in JOGL?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I'm trying to move the camera in jogl but my code doesn't seem to do anything. How do you move the camera with keyboard input? I'm drawing a rotating hexagon and I want to move the camera but I can't seem to get it working. This is my code:

```
import javax.media.opengl.*;
import javax.media.opengl.awt.*;
import com.sun.opengl.util.*;
import com.sun.opengl.util.gl2.GLUT;
import javax.media.opengl.glu.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Rotation2 extends JFrame implements GLEventListener, KeyListener
{
    GLCanvas canvas;
    Animator an;

    public Rotation2()
    {

        canvas=new GLCanvas();
        an=new Animator(canvas);
        add(canvas);
        canvas.addGLEventListener(this);
        canvas.addKeyListener(this);
        setSize(600,400);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        an.start();

    }
    double eyeX = 0;
    double eyeY = 0;
    double eyeZ = 0;

    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable)
    {
        GL2 gl=drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        GLU glu = new GLU();
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glOrtho(-300,300,-200,200,200,-200);
        //gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
        //glu.gluLookAt(5, 5, 5,0, 0, 0, 1, 100, 0);
        gl.glClearDepth(1.0f);                   // Set background depth to farthest
        gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST);   // Enable depth testing for z-culling
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL2.GL_LEQUAL);    // Set the type of depth-test
    }
    double x=0;

    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable)
    {
        GL2 gl=drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        GLU glu=new GLU();

        //gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glScaled(2,2,2);
        gl.glRotated(x,1,1,1);
        x+=.05;

        glu.gluLookAt(eyeX, eyeY, 2,0, 0, 0, 1, 100, 0);

        gl.glColor3f(0,1f,0);
        // front
        gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_POLYGON);
        gl.glVertex3d(25,50,25);
        gl.glVertex3d(-25,50,25);
        gl.glVertex3d(-50,0,25);
        gl.glVertex3d(-25,-50,25);
        gl.glVertex3d(25,-50,25);
        gl.glVertex3d(50,0,25);
        gl.glEnd();
        //left
        gl.glColor3f(1f,1f,0);
        gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_POLYGON);
        gl.glVertex3d(25,50,-25);
        gl.glVertex3d(-25,50,-25);
        gl.glVertex3d(-50,0,-25);
        gl.glVertex3d(-25,-50,-25);
        gl.glVertex3d(25,-50,-25);
        gl.glVertex3d(50,0,-25);

        gl.glEnd();


        gl.glColor3f(1f,0f,0);
        gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_POLYGON);

        gl.glVertex3d(25,50,25);
        gl.glVertex3d(25,50,-25);
        gl.glVertex3d(-25,50,-25);
        gl.glVertex3d(-25,50,25);

        gl.glEnd();

        gl.glColor3f(0f,0f,1f);
        gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_POLYGON);

        gl.glVertex3d(-25,50,25);
        gl.glVertex3d(-25,50,-25);
        gl.glVertex3d(-50,0,-25);
        gl.glVertex3d(-50,0,25);

        gl.glEnd();

        gl.glColor3f(1f,1f,1f);
        gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_POLYGON);

        gl.glVertex3d(-50,0,25);
        gl.glVertex3d(-50,0,-25);
        gl.glVertex3d(-25,-50,-25);
        gl.glVertex3d(-25,-50,25);

        gl.glEnd();

        gl.glColor3f(0,1f,1f);

        gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_POLYGON);

        gl.glVertex3d(-25,-50,25);
        gl.glVertex3d(-25,-50,-25);
        gl.glVertex3d(25,-50,-25);
        gl.glVertex3d(25,-50,25);
        gl.glEnd();

        gl.glColor3f(1,0f,1f);

        gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_POLYGON);
        gl.glVertex3d(25,-50,25);
        gl.glVertex3d(25,-50,-25);
        gl.glVertex3d(50,0,-25);
        gl.glVertex3d(50,0,25);

        gl.glEnd();

        gl.glColor3f(.2f,1f,.2f);

        gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_POLYGON);

        gl.glVertex3d(50,0,25);
        gl.glVertex3d(50,0,-25);
        gl.glVertex3d(25,50,-25);
        gl.glVertex3d(25,50,25);

        gl.glEnd();
        //gl.glPopMatrix();


    }

    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable,int x,int y,int width,int height)
    {}
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable)
    {}


    public static void main(String[] ar)
    {

        new Rotation2();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_X) {
            eyeX++;
        }
        else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_Y) {
            eyeY++;
        }
        else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_Z) {
            eyeZ++;
        }
        else {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

that's deprecated opengl, forget it.

You are also using a very old jogl, update it, go on [jogamp.org](http://jogamp.org/), under "Builds / Download" click on "zip", then download `jogamp-all-platforms.7z` extract it and set jogl as explained [here](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE)

Take this [Hello Triangle](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/tree/master/jogl-samples/src/helloTriangle).

It uses already the `keyListener`, just copy the code you wrote for the `keyTyped` and paste it under `keyPressed` (you have to use the jogamp keyListener, what you use in your sample is instead the java awt one).

Let us know if you have any problem :)

Comment: I'm having trouble setting up the JOGL library in Netbeans. I've downloaded the zip file and extracted it to my C drive and added the library in Netbeans but I package does not exist error on almost every import.

Comment: And another problem is that I need to use the version I'm already using due to code compatibility because I'm not sure how this will work with my textures.

Comment: You get errors at import because the `GL` object has been moved,`javax.media.opengl` is the old location. Don't worry about the textures, you can use [jgli](https://github.com/elect86/jgli) to handle every possible kind of texture properly. Which textures do you have (i.e. formats)?

Comment: I'm also getting "Uncompilable source code - package framework does not exist" 

I'm just applying "jpeg" or "png"s to quads really but I'm just really new with textures and JOGL in general. I just want to get it working because I'm on a deadline.

Comment: Trust me, you will have no problem updating jogl. Use this [Hello Texture](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/tree/master/jogl-samples/src/helloTexture) instead. It loads a png image on a square and rotate it. It is perfect for your case

Comment: You should really follow elect's advises, especially the instructions in our wiki. I'm sorry, another member showed you some examples using obsolete versions of JOGL in an answer of your other question on JOGL and it just causes some confusion now.